# Code Below doesn't result in Logout Button to Work, what is wrong?

Tags: ios, swift

Code Below doesn't result in Logout Button to Work, what is wrong?!?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // Set Log Out Button
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    // Data option
    let data = ["Log Out"]
    
    // Supply Data Source and Delegate Self
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

// Add an externsion to inform Data Source and Delegate
extension ProfileViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    // Deque row and style text
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .red
        return cell
    }
    
    // Make logout to occur when user log outs - unhighlight cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        
    // Create an alert to Log Out
        let actionsheet = UIAlertController(title: "",
                                            message: "",
                                            preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out",
                                            style: .destructive,
                                            handler: { [weak self] _ in
            
                                            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                                                return
                                            }
            
                                            do {
                                                try FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signOut()
                                                let vc = LogInViewController()
                                                let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                                                nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                                                strongSelf.present(nav, animated: true)
                                            }
                                            catch {
                                                print("Failed to log out")
                                            }
}))
        
        actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                            style: .cancel,
                                            handler: nil))
        
    present(actionsheet, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have used `didDeselectRowAt` instead of `didSelectRowAt`. `didSelectRowAt` is what gets called when user taps on cell and selects it,  `didDeselectRowAt` gets called when cell is deselected.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let actionsheet = UIAlertController(title: "",
                                            message: "",
                                            preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out",
                                            style: .destructive,
                                            handler: { [weak self] _ in

                                                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                                                    return
                                                }

                                                do {
                                                    try FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signOut()
                                                    let vc = LogInViewController()
                                                    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                                                    nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                                                    strongSelf.present(nav, animated: true)
                                                }
                                                catch {
                                                    print("Failed to log out")
                                                }
                                            }))

        actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                            style: .cancel,
                                            handler: nil))

        present(actionsheet, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks....its the little things, didn't even notice!